# how to create word vector

Tags: nlp, neural-network, word2vec

How to create word vector? I used one hot key to create word vector, but it is very huge and not generalized for similar semantic word. So I have heard about word vector using neural network that finds word similarity and word vector. So I wanted to know how to generate this vector (algorithm) or good material to start creating word vector ?.

Comment: you might want to start with type x document matrix, tf-idf weighting, and cosine similarity. google it. you'll get a nice insight of the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Word-vectors or so-called distributed representations have a long history by now, starting perhaps from work of S. Bengio (*Bengio, Y., Ducharme, R., & Vincent, P. (2001).A neural probabilistic language model. NIPS.*) where he obtained word-vectors as by-product of training neural-net lanuage model.

A lot of researches demonstrated that these vectors do capture semantic relationship between words (see for example http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/206777/338_Paper.pdf). Also this important paper (http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.0398) by Collobert et al, is a good starting point with understanding word vectors, the way they are obtained and used.

Besides word2vec there is a lot of methods to obtain them. Expamples include SENNA embeddings by Collobert et al (http://ronan.collobert.com/senna/), RNN embeddings by T. Mikolov that can be computed using RNNToolkit (http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~imikolov/rnnlm/) and much more. For English, ready-made embeddings can be downloaded from these web-sites. word2vec really uses skip-gram model (not neural network model).  Another fast code for computing  word representations is GloVe (http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/). It is an open question whatever deep neural networks are essential for obtaining good embeddings or not.

Depending of your application, you may prefer using different types of word-vectors, so its a good idea to try several popular algorithms and see what works better for you.

Answer (score 3):

I think the thing you mean is Word2Vec (https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/). It trains N-dimensional word vectors of documents based on a given corpus. So in my understanding of word2vec the neural network is just used to aggregate the dimensions of the document vector and also capturing some relationship between words. But what should be mentioned is that this is not really semantically related, it just reflects the structural relationship in your training body.

If you want to capture semantic relatedness have a look a WordNet based measures, for instance implemented is these libaries:

- Java: https://code.google.com/p/ws4j/
- Perl: http://wn-similarity.sourceforge.net/

To get started with word2vec you can use their pretrained vectors. You should find all information about this at https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/.

When you seek for a java implementation. This is a good starting point: http://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec.html

I hope this helps

Best wishes